# Address book problem when user edit the billing address

Tags: 7, commerce

i just installed [commerce address book](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook) module but i noticed that when authenticated users try to edit their billing address they have some options in the bottom that seems very strange and not necessary.

The fist one is : The user is able to change the owner of the account 
and the second is : The user can change the status from active to disabled.

I think that these options should not be there.

Do you know how can i disable?

Answer (score 0):

I found this patch which worked for me: http://drupal.org/node/1774932